# Android App Help

Tags: android, sockets, asynchronous

I made a thread similar to this, but I want to elaborate.

Essentially I want to make an app that can be started up, run in the background and will receive messages from a server (the server is a linux server up that currently sends out messages with updates on a system I have to know about) and then give a notice to the person about the message and just kinda stay passively in the back unless it's closed down entirely. I am very new to Android and I have a similar function up on the web, but a web app is required. Any suggestions on what I should read first or anyone know a good tutorial of something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the title of this question, "Android App Help" is way too generic. Maybe something like "Polling from a server with a background android app" would suit it better?

Answer (score 0):

Start there : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Answer (score 0):

start reading about services , (services are working in background ) ; and after , read about notifications in android : 
refer this two links :

[tuto services 1](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=356)

[tuto services 2](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx)

[tuto services 3](http://www.tutos-android.com/tag/tuto-service-android)